# Stop Batch file if its being run from a drive

Tags: batch-file

Hi I want to stop a batch file if it is being run from a particular drive. I have tried somehting like this, it doesn't work though. I would appreciate it if someone has a better idea.

```
if %CD%=="^.*C:\" (goto :CDrive)
```

Where :CDrive is an error message saying that the user is trying to run it from the wrong drive.

Cheers
Chris

Comment: I'm not even sure why you would expect that to work. At the very least the backslash at the end would make for an invalid regex. Not to mention that `cmd` doesn't support regular expressions anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a substring to check:

```
if "%CD:~0,2%"=="C:" goto CDrive
```

Another option might be that you just explicitly set the drive you're expecting:

```
pushd X:
```

or use full paths instead of relative ones.