# Windows 10: How can I determine whether a batch file is being run from network mapped drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to prevent a batch file from being run if it is being run from a network location / mapped drive. Is it possible to know if PWD is a mapped drive  / network location?

NOTE: This is different from below SO post. In the below post, user knows drive letter on which he wants to prevent running the batch.

[Stop Batch file if its being run from a drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579731/stop-batch-file-if-its-being-run-from-a-drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%~d0` references "**drive**" on which the executed batch file is stored, i.e. drive letter and colon on batch file is stored on a storage media (local hard disk, USB memory stick, CD/DVD drive, etc. or a network resource with a drive letter assigned (network drive), or two backslashes on batch file is stored on a network resource and was started using a UNC path.

The command `net` with parameter `use` outputs the list of network resources with a drive letter assigned which can be searched for the drive letter of the currently executed batch file.

```
@echo off
if "%~d0" == "\\" (
    echo Batch file is started using UNC path "%~dp0".
    goto :EOF
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:" %~d0 " >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Batch file is started from network drive %~d0.
    goto :EOF
)
echo Okay running batch file from drive %~d0.
```

**Note:** The search string can be also just `%~d0` instead of `" %~d0 "`. The additional spaces requiring the quotes just make sure to find a line with drive letter and colon in second column of `net use` output.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains modifier `~d` on referencing an argument of a batch file like argument 0 which is always the currently processed batch file.
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `net /?` and `net use /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.